# Installing Boost when creating custom binaries

Tags: boost

The section "**5.2 Or, Build Custom Binaries**" from the [Boost Getting Started on UNIX Variants](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) guide explains how to bootstrap `b2`, how to install it within the prefix you wish, and how to use `b2` for building Boost with the toolset you prefer... but... how do you install Boost into the install prefix after the build? I couldn't find that in that page, nor by googling it either.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
b2 install
```

It's mentioned in the [quick instructions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#easy-build-and-install).